# pandas Panel max

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, panel

I have pandas.Panel4D object and I would like to find the maximum of the all values.

The current way:

```
p4d.max().max().max().max()
```

In there a better way to achieve the same result?

(np.max(p4d) does not work.)

Also is there is an equivalent for idxmax for panel and panel4D?

Comment: does `np.max(p4d)` work?

Comment: OK you could do `np.max(p4d.values.ravel())` to get the maximum of all values, also `idxmax` is only valid for dataframes or series so you have to access a specific axis and then call `idxmax`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `max` on the `values` attribute.

```
pd.Panel4D(np.arange(16).reshape(2, 2, 2, 2)).values.max()

15
```

numpy `ndarray` `max` method returns the maximum over the entire structure unless you specify an axis.  You can access the underlying `ndarray` via the `values` attribute.